# Functorial Algebraic Geometry - Schemes as Gluing Construction

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, algebraic-groups

Coming from a category theory background and having no experience with smooth manifolds the definition of a *scheme* as certain functors $\mathsf{CRing} \longrightarrow \mathsf{Set}$ feels much more natural to me than the definition as *locally ringed space*. Yet, I'm not really sold on the current way of constructing schemes of functors. Let me explain.

Given a representing functor $\mathsf{CRing(A,-)}$ (which I will call **affine scheme**), the usual *Zariski-Topology* on $A$ lets us define the notion of an *open subfunctor* $X \subseteq \mathsf{CRing}(A,-)$, which I find quite natural. What confuses me are the following steps: Having the notion of open subfunctor of an affine scheme, we can define openness for arbitrary subfunctors of arbitrary functors $\mathsf{CRing} \longrightarrow \mathsf{Set}$. We then restrict our attention to those functors, which satisfy some sort of gluing condition, that is to say we consider sheaves on the Zariski-site. The final step to obtain schemes is to restrict further to those sheaves, which admit a cover by affine schemes.

I don't really get the following behaviour: We start with some sort of topology on subfunctors of affine schemes, which we generalize to arbitrary functors. So to me it feels like sheaves on the Zariski-site should already come equipped with the property of having a cover by affines, but they obviously do **not**. Why is that?

I don't have much experience with sites yet, but I think I will be able to figure out sometime, where the definition of a sheaf on a site breaks regarding providing a cover. The next question is of more importance to me, because I could not figure out where (or if?) the following alternative approach to schemes fails.

> **Why don't we (or can we) define the category of schemes as follows?**
> The category of schemes $\mathsf{Sch}$ is the smallest full subcategory of $[\![\mathsf{CRing},\mathsf{Set}]\!]$ containing the affine schemes and being closed under forming colimits of gluing dates of open subfunctors of affine schemes (gluing dates being defined as in the usual topological setting).

Thank you very much for your time and considerations!

Comment: We restrict to Zariski sheaves because we already know that certain diagrams of affine schemes "should" be colimit diagrams, yet are not so in the category of presheaves. Once you fix this, the category of schemes is indeed defined by closure under gluing. See the introduction and §3.5 [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.17863/CAM.384).

Comment: Silly me. Your thesis is on my *to read* list for a while now, but when writing my question I didn’t think of it... Anyway, thank you very much for your comment and for the hint!